# Is there a way to clear the start destination off a navStack in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using jetpack compose in my app. On debug, my start destination is a debug screen, but on release I instantly navigate from the debug screen to the login screen. My flow is as follow.
Debug: debug screen -> login screen -> logged in screen
Release: login screen -> logged in screen.

Since I instantly navigate to the login screen on release from the debug screen, when i press the back button on the login screen the app doesnt close. Instead it navigates to the debug screen and instantly navigates to the login screen (this happens so quickly the user doesnt see it.

Any suggestions on what I can do here?

I tried making my startDestination in my navhost = an if else statement, but that seems kinda messy and outside coding convention.

I want whenever the user presses the back button on the login screen on release for the app to close. I also want for the app to close when the user presses the back button on the debug screen on debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a string in your Gradle file that changes based on the build variant, and use it as the start destination. This can be done by setting the "START_DESTINATION" field in the "buildConfigField" block for each build type.

```
android {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                buildConfigField "String", "START_DESTINATON", "debugScreen"
            }
            release {
                buildConfigField "String", "START_DESTINATON", "loginScreen"
            }
        }
    }
```

To use this string as the start destination in your NavHost, you can access it through the BuildConfig class.

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = BuildConfig.START_DESTINATION) {
    composable("debugScreen") { DebugScreen(/*...*/) }
    composable("loginScreen") { LoginScreen(/*...*/) }
}
```